# Supertrace on Weyl algebra

Tags: weyl-algebra, super-algebra

Consider Weyl algebra, i.e. the algebra of $x^i$ and $p_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$,
its elements are differential operators $F(x,p)$. Weyl algebra is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded, hence one ask if there exists a supertrace. It turns out that there is one
$$str\, F(x,p)=F(0,0)$$
I am looking for original references where this fact was established, some general comments are also welcome. Say, Pinczon et al in
a 2005 paper "[Supertrace and superquadratic Lie structure on the Weyl algebra, with applications to formal inverse Weyl transform](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507092)" mention this fact without any refs.

Comment: I found the linked paper very confusing.  At some point they say: "The Weyl algebra W is a Lie algebra with bracket denoted by [.,.]L , and since it is naturally Z2-graded, W is a Lie superalgebra with bracket denoted by [.,.]."  That may work for the Weyl algebra because [W,W] is central, but is this true in general?  The Jacobi identity that has to be satisfied is different in both cases.  Writing $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_1$ for the 2-graded Lie algebra, the Jacobi identity has 4 graded components: $000$, $001$, $011$ and $111$.  (continued below)

Comment: The first three are the same if we think of $\mathfrak{g}$ as a Lie superalgebra, but the last component is different.  In the Lie algebra case it defines an element in $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}_0}(\Lambda^3\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_1)$ whereas in the Lie superalgebra case it defines an element in $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}_0}(\textrm{Sym}^3\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_1)$

Comment: I think they had the following simple fact in mind. If a given associative algebra is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded then one can construct a Lie algebra and a Lie superalgebra, where the bracket is (graded) commutator. For example, one can ask about traces and supertraces at the same time

Comment: Thanks.  I see.  That's indeed true, just not exactly what is stated in the paper.